# Incorrect DLL is loaded from windows PATH instead of manifest

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, dllregistration, comtypes

I have a problem when registering a COM server written in Python that appears to be related to the standard uuid Python module.

In am running 32-bit Python 2.7.9 on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.

When I include the uuid module in my server, there is a failure during the registering or unregistering processes (using regsvr32). Everything seems to work if I remove uuid from my project.

I have used Dependency Walker to investigate. I don't have a detailed understanding of what is going on, but it is clear that the process finds a copy of MSVCR90.DLL in the Windows PATH, which happens to be the wrong version of the DLL, so a failure follows.

Now I can remove this particular MSVCR90.DLL file from the path, but it doesn't belong to me! It is in a distribution of some Intel software installed by our IT department! And anyway, I would like to be able to distribute my server to other users and have no control over the configuration of their machines.

The other thing to note is that I have provided the correct version of MSVCR90.DLL in a manifest that is sitting beside my COM server DLL (as is usual for distributing a Python-based executable of DLL). So I would expect the Python uuid module to find THAT DLL and use it.

I'm completely stuck. Can anyone offer a solution to this?

Here are some excerpts from the Dependency Walker. I see the incorrect DLL loaded from the Windows PATH

```
00:00:04.742: LoadLibraryA("msvcr90.dll") called from "c:\proj_py\gtxl\sxs\dist\_CTYPES.PYD" at address 0x1D1A9742.
00:00:04.773: Loaded "c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL" at address 0x59AE0000.  Successfully hooked module.
```

A few lines below I see this (first and last lines were displayed in red)

```
00:00:12.807: DllMain(0x59AE0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL" returned 0 (0x0).
00:00:12.839: DllMain(0x59AE0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL" called.
00:00:12.839: DllMain(0x59AE0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL" returned 0 (0x0).
00:00:12.854: Unloaded "c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL" at address 0x59AE0000.
00:00:12.870: LoadLibraryA("msvcr90.dll") returned NULL. Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed (1114).
```

which seems to be the point of error.

Now, it looks to me that a Python DLL called _CTYPES.PYD causes the unwanted DLL it be loaded. I presume that the uuid module is calling the Python ctypes module which is somehow associated with _ctypes.pyd.

Does this mean there is a problem with _ctypes.pyd in the Python 2.7.9 distribution?

One last clue, perhaps. When I remove the offending DLL from the PATH. Registration proceeds without error. However, in Dependency Walker I see this

```
00:00:03.728: LoadLibraryA("msvcr90.dll") called from "c:\proj_py\gtxl\sxs\dist\_CTYPES.PYD" at address 0x1D1A9742.
00:00:03.759: LoadLibraryA("msvcr90.dll") returned NULL. Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (193).
```

with the second line highlighted in red. It seems that this attempt fails, but registration just proceeds anyway (and I don't see any other references to msvcr90.dll).

Here are the files of a simple example that causes the problem. I am using the Python comtypes package in combination with py2exe to create the server.

An IDL file `test.idl` that must be complied by the MIDL complier

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
        uuid(EAE82E0D-312C-4C23-99D8-8BA686D89B72),
        dual,
        oleautomation
]
interface IMSLTest : IDispatch {
        HRESULT TestMethod([in] INT a, [in] INT b, [out, retval] INT *presult);
}

[
      uuid(7587E538-7AFD-4663-A444-34F32997B0E9)
]
library MSLTestLib
{
        importlib("stdole2.tlb");

        [uuid(B7051914-24BC-4FBB-A447-F75A9FA8E295)]
              coclass MyObject {
              [default] interface IMSLTest;
        };
};
```

A source file for the Python COM server, `server.py`

```
import comtypes
import comtypes.server.inprocserver

import uuid

# # generate wrapper code for the type library, this needs
# # to be done only once (but also each time the IDL file changes)
# # !!! NB  It needs to be done before py2exe is run !!!
# from comtypes.client import GetModule
# GetModule("test.tlb")

# Something has been created here
from comtypes.gen.MSLTestLib import MyObject

class MyObjectImpl(MyObject):

    # registry entries
    _reg_threading_ = "Both"
    _reg_progid_ = "MSLTestLib.MyObject"
    _reg_desc_ = "A test COM server"
    _reg_clsctx_ = comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER

    def __init__(self):
        MyObject.__init__(self)
        l = uuid.uuid4().int

    def TestMethod(self,a,b):
        return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from comtypes.server.register import UseCommandLine
    UseCommandLine(MyObjectImpl)

    # # Does it work?
    # # Must register the server using the two lines above first, 
    # # then uncomment these and comment out those above.
    # from comtypes.client import CreateObject
    # x = CreateObject("MSLTestLib.MyObject")
    # print x.TestMethod(3,4)
```

And a configuration file for py2exe, `setup.py` (the glob of files to put in the manifest is specific to my setup)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob

data_files = [
        ("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\usr\lib\msvcr\*.*'))
    ]

class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        # for the version info resources (Properties -- Version)
        self.version = "0.0.0"
        self.company_name = "Mine"
        self.copyright = "c 2015"
        self.name = "Test"

my_com_server_target = Target(
    description = "A test server",
    # use module name for win32com exe/dll server
    modules = ["server"],
    # the following line embeds the typelib within the dll
    other_resources = [("TYPELIB", 1, open(r"test.tlb", "rb").read())],
    # specify which type of com server you want (exe and/or dll)
    create_exe = False,
    create_dll = True
)

includes = ["win32com" ,"win32service", "win32serviceutil", "win32event"]
excludes = ['tcl', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'distutils','numpy','unittest']
packages = []
dll_excludes = [
    'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll', 
    'SHFOLDER.dll', 
    'Secur32.dll', 
    'MPR.dll', 
    'CRYPT32.dll', 
    'KERNELBASE.dll',
]
setup(
    data_files=data_files, 
    options={ "py2exe":
        dict(
            includes=includes,
            excludes=excludes,
            packages=packages,
            dll_excludes=dll_excludes,
            ascii=False,
            bundle_files=3,
            # skip_archive=True
        )      
    },
    ctypes_com_server = [my_com_server_target],
    zipfile=None,
)
```

Here is the contents of my manifest file`Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest`, which sits in a folder called `Microsoft.VC90.CRT`, together with `msvcr90.dll`, that is in the same directory as my COM server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. -->
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <noInheritable/>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
        version="9.0.21022.8"
        processorArchitecture="x86"
        publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"
    >
    </assemblyIdentity>
    <file name="msvcr90.dll" /> 
</assembly>
```

There is also an embedded manifest in the DLL. This was generated automatically by py2exe, without any content from me. Here it is

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I have the *exact* same issue!  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. I didn't find a satisfactory solution

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for responding though!  I'm fighting this battle now.  I'll post a resolution if I can find one.  I've found instructions for this, and it seems like you did everything exactly right, so it's baffling...